# how to search data in tableview from a database javafx

Tags: java, sql, javafx

```
public void Search(ActionEvent event)
{
    try
    {
        Connection conn = SqliteConnection.Connector();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT FROM Studentlist WHERE ID LIKE ?% ");
        ps.setString(1, this.search.getText());

        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(String.valueOf(ps));
        while (rs.next())
        {
            this.data.add(new StudentData(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5), rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7)));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I am trying to search data by id from the database through tableview javafx gui

i want it to return all the data starting with the letters i input in the textfield

i connected the database through the class and method i created `SqliteConnection.Connector();` prepared a string got the value from the search textfield... `this.data` is the name of observablelist.. my issue is i dont get any result in the tableview when i type a valid ID

Comment: The query used the db will be something like `SELECT FROM Studentlist WHERE ID LIKE "input"%` which is incorrect SQL syntax

Comment: This is marked as duplicate but it talks about observable list in a tableview and i agree it talks about the use of like in database

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(String.valueOf(ps));
```

You want to do

```
ResultSet rs =  ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: i changed`'PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT FROM Studentlist WHERE ID LIKE '?'%");
            ps.setString(1, this.search.getText());

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();`but still not showing search results

Comment: put the % in your setString method like this:  ps.setString(1, this.search.getText()+"%");  and of course remove the % from your  prepareStatement function argument.